# Transform string of objects into elements of object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, underscore.js

I have this below string of objects as shown below.

```
[0,5]
   0: "A123  G  2323232"
   1: "F345  G  345667"
   2: "T677  G  -34343"
   3: "G454  G  4343"
   4: ""
```

As you can see  "A123  G  2323232" is a string which has tab seperated values in it.

I would like to have a final output as follows.

```
[0,4]
   0: 
     UserId:A123
     Type:  G
     Values: 2323232
   1: 
     UserId: F345  
     Type:  G
     Values: 345667
   2: 
     UserId: T677  
     Type:  G
     Values: -34343
   3: 
     UserId: G454  
     Type:  G
     Values: 4343
```

Please note. the 4th element is empty string. so it should not transform to final data.

Can anyone please suggest how to distribute this to different elements.

Comment: Separate your String using  [split()](http://http://jsfiddle.net/K3D6d/5/) Function and then append that result to particular ID.

Comment: @MaulikBhatt- can you show me an example and i can have a look

Comment: See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/mkn5vojt/)

Comment: Please define "tabs"! Are they two adjacent spaces `'  '`? Or are they `\t`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could match non space parts and deconstruct the array to the wanted properties and return an object.

```js
var data = ["A123  G  2323232", "F345  G  345667", "T677  G  -34343", "G454  G  4343", ""],
    result = data
        .filter(Boolean)
        .map(s => {
            var [UserId, Type, Values] = s.match(/[^ ]+/g);
            return { UserId, Type, Values };
        });
                
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can split each string into its individual pieces of data, and then map those pieces into an object with the properties you want. Here's what it would look like:

```js
var data = ["A123  G  2323232","F345  G  345667","T677  G  -34343","G454  G  4343", ""];
/* ES6 Syntax */
var objects = data.filter(str => str !== "").map(function (str) {
  var [UserId, Type, Values] = str.split("  ");
  return { UserId, Type, Values };
});

/* ES5 Syntax */
var objectsES5 = data.filter(function (str) {
  return str !== "";
}).map(function (str) {
  var split = str.split("  ");
  return {
    UserId: split[0],
    Type: split[1],
    Values: split[2]
  };
});

console.log(objects);
```

Comment: `map` won't work. What about the empty string at the end of the original array.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir missed that, thanks. Nina's solution adds that with `.filter(Boolean)`. That's probably the best way to do it, but for the sake of not copying her idea, I will filter on empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Use a combo of `reduce` and `split`:

```js
var strings = [
  "A123 G 2323232",
  "F345 G 345667",
  "T677 G -34343",
  "G454 G 4343",
  ""
];

var result = strings.reduce(function(res, str) {  // for each string in strings arrays
  var parts = str.split("\t");                    // split the string by tabs
  if(parts.length === 3) {                        // if the string is valid (the splitting yielded 3 parts)
    res.push({                                    // then add an object to the result array using the parts we got
      UserID: parts[0],
      Type: parts[1],
      Values: parts[2]
    });
  }
  return res;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @Rihana I hard copied your strings that didn't have tabs `\t` in them. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using javascript `filter()` and `map()` methods like following.

```js
var array = ["A123  G  2323232",
             "F345  G  345667",
             "T677  G  -34343",
             "G454  G  4343",
             ""];

var result = array.filter(function(item) {
  return item.trim();
}).map(function(item) {
  var split = item.split('  ');
  
  return {
    UserId: split[0],
    Type: split[1],
    Values: split[2]
  };
});

console.log(result);
```