# transform array into elements of object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, object, underscore.js

This is with respect to the following

[Transform string of objects into elements of object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45887095/transform-string-of-objects-into-elements-of-object?noredirect=1#comment78733778_45887095)

As per that, i had a different data. Instead of that data, i have comma seperated values. How can i put all those values in element. Any Suggestion please.

Here is my new data.

```
[0,5]
0: "A123,G,2323232"
1: "F345,G,345667"
2: "T677,G,-34343"
3: "G454,G,4343"
4: ""
```

Can someone please let me know how to convert above commas values present in an array into the following

```
[0,4]
0: 
 UserId:A123
 Type:  G
 Values: 2323232
1: 
 UserId: F345  
 Type:  G
 Values: 345667
2: 
 UserId: T677  
 Type:  G
 Values: -34343
3: 
 UserId: G454  
 Type:  G
 Values: 4343
```

Comment: I think there's a problem with the data structure that you are trying to handle. using Regex as @Kyon can solved the problem, but I think you should formalize the data model that used here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var data = ["A123,G,2323232", "F345,G,345667", "T677,G,-34343", "G454,G,4343", ""],
    result = data
        .filter(Boolean)
        .map(s => {
            var [UserId, Type, Values] = s.match(/[^,]+/g);
            return { UserId, Type, Values };
        });
                
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @Rihana don't forget to mark this as solved if your problem is solved with this code snippet.